# MySql "NOT IN" clause not recognized in phpMyAdmin 4.5.0.2

Tags: phpmyadmin

A simple SQL statement such as

```
SELECT 1 from MyTable WHERE 1 NOT IN (2);
```

generates:

```
4 Errors were found during analysis.

    1. Unrecognized keyword (near "NOT IN" at position 30)
    2. Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 37)
    3. Unexpected token. (near "2" at position 38)
    4. Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 39)
```

I just noticed on the phpMYAdmin website "Current version compatible with PHP 5.5 to 7.0 and MySQL 5.5".  The version of MySql I am using is 5.6.26. Could this be the problem?  The above SQL certain des not cause a problem when entered directly via mysql.exe (MySql Console).

Comment: Your query works fine for me; I tried "SELECT 1 from actor WHERE 1 NOT IN (2)" on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/ which is currently running 4.5.0.2. Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I've edited my question to specify that I am using MySql 5.6, which could possibly be an incompatibility issue since the phpMyAdmin site states that it is compatible with MySql 5.5.

Comment: I can confirm this problem in MySQL 5.7.8 and opened an issue at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11518

Comment: Thanks.  Misery loves company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed for the upcoming phpMyAdmin 4.5.1.