# MySQL not supporting "NOT IN" via phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running MySQL version 5.6.20 using phpMyAdmin version 4.5.0.2

I am trying to do a simple `NOT IN` query, but phpMyAdmin is complaining saying it is invalid:

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT IN" ...

I know `NOT IN` is supported via php. What have I missed?

```
SELECT gempageid FROM gempage gp
WHERE gempageid NOT IN 
(
    SELECT gempageid FROM gempage gp2 WHERE grade <> 1
)
```

I've noticed other syntax features giving errors to that should work: e.g. `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: Might it be that you are accidentally using some exotic white space characters in your queries?

Comment: Constructs like `WHERE EXIST` or `NOT IN` do not have to be "supported by php" or similar. That language or tool is irrelevant in that. It is the MySQL service that interprets and processes the queries. Everything outside treats the queries as simple string. So for a test: try to execute the same queries right inside MySQL.

Comment: @arkascha No chance of invalid characters. I've tried 100 different ways - simple keying in, copy and paste from examples on the web. I mainly mention `php` for my own sanity, knowing it should work.

Comment: The queries or tokens are valid and every sane MySQL version supports them.

Comment: If you are copying from a website, take care of the special characters. Some of them seems spaces, but there aren't. The best you can do is write manually or test the same query outside php or phpmyadmin (directly to the mysql server from a console client for example)

Comment: Thanks @MarcosPérezGude - I have keyed in every character and am positive there are no white space characters other than spaces. I am completely stumped. I've added a screenshot, in case it is of any value.

Comment: The resultant query is different than the query you submitted. It is replacing the inner `SELECT` with a `LIMIT`. Strange, it seems from phpmyadmin huh?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude phpmyadmin always adds a `LIMIT` to the query. I cut and paste my query into my live site phpMyAdmin and it works fine. I may have to reinstall phpMyAdmin. I'll try a reboot first...

Comment: Tried in MySQL-5.7.13, no problem with similar SQL has "NOT IN",  could you provide any samples(table structure and some records)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql "NOT IN" clause not recognized in phpMyAdmin 4.5.0.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792381/mysql-not-in-clause-not-recognized-in-phpmyadmin-4-5-0-2)

Comment: @Jocelyn Yes, thank you. I had already found that post (and posted the answer below). For some reason, that post did not show up in the various suggested links. I will mark my answer as accepted in a couple of days and it will the end of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a phpMyAdmin problem. I found an [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792381/mysql-not-in-clause-not-recognized-in-phpmyadmin-4-5-0-2).

Supposedly fixed in phpMyAdmin 4.5.1. I will upgrade.

**UPDATE**
I upgraded to 4.6.3 and can confirm it is fixed.